# I am trying to make a calculator that takes the whole equation and does not use eval()

Tags: python

I am trying to make a calculator that doesn't use eval() and take the whole equation as a string. Also I can't use any libraries, modules, etc. I've managed to make something but I can't figure out how to make it to first do the multiplication and division and then the rest.
It doesn't give me an error but it does this:
4 + 4 = 8

4 + 4 * 4 = 20

4 + 4 * 4 + 4 = 4

Edit: So I found where the problem was, but it still doesn't function right. The problem was that the code doesn't even reach the part where it finds the "*". I'll mark with an arrow where it doesn't reach it.

Here is the code and thanks in advance:

```
print("Calculator")

# All the numbers
def numbers(num):
    return(
        num == "0"
        or num == "1"
        or num == "2"
        or num == "3"
        or num == "4"
        or num == "5"
        or num == "6"
        or num == "7"
        or num == "8"
        or num == "9"
    )

# All the operators
def operator(oprt):
    return(
        oprt == "+"
        or oprt == "-"
        or oprt == "*"
        or oprt == "/"
    )

# Removes all the spaces
def remove_spaces(string):
    string = string.replace(" ", "")
    return string

# Does the math between two numbers
def operation(string, num1, num2):
    if string == "+":
        return num1 + num2
    if string == "-":
        return num1 - num2
    if string == "*":
        return num1 * num2
    if string == "/":
        return num1 / num2

# Tests how long the number is
def test_number(numstr):
    n = 0
    num = ""

    try:
        while numbers(numstr[n]):
            num += numstr[n]
            n += 1
    except:
        pass

    return(int(num), n)

# Solves the equation
def eval_equation(eq):
    negative = False

    # Removes the spaces
    eq = remove_spaces(eq)

    while True:
        try:
            # Checks if the first number is negative
            if eq[0] == "-":
                negative = True
                eq = eq[1:]

            # Solves the multiplication first
            i = 0
            eqTemp = ""
            if "*" in eq:
                try:
                    while i < len(eq):
                        if eq[i] == "+" or eq[i] == "-" or eq[i] == "/":
                            eqTemp = eqTemp + eq[:i + 1]
                            print(f"eqTemp = {eqTemp}")
                            eq = eq[i + 1:]
                            print(f"eq = {eq}")
                        elif eq[i] == "*": # <-------this is the problem----
                            break
                            print(f"eqTemp = {eqTemp}")
                            print(f"eq = {eq}")
                            
                            
                        i += 1
                except:
                    i = 0

            # Checks the lenght of the number
            number1 = test_number(eq)[0]

            # Returns the "-" in the negative number
            if negative == True:
                number1 = -number1
                negative = False

            # Removes the first number from the string to continue with the next
            endNumber1 = test_number(eq)[1]
            eq = eq[endNumber1:]

            # Checks for any more numbers
            if eq == "":
                return number1

            # This is the operator sign
            op = eq[0]
            eq = eq[1:]

            # Repeats the same process with the other number
            number2 = test_number(eq)[0]
            endNumber2 = test_number(eq)[1]

            result = operation(op, number1, number2)
            
            # Takes the result and passes it as to the first number along with the rest of the equation
            number1 = result
            eq = str(number1) + eq[endNumber2:]

            eq = eqTemp + eq

        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
            break
    
    return number1
    

# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        equation = input(": ")
        print(eval_equation(equation))
```

Comment: You’ve embarked on a nontrivial — and very exciting — topic of programming. I recommend you have a look at the first few chapters of [*Crafting Interpreters*](https://craftinginterpreters.com/) (you can read it online for free!), it’s a great resource for learning how to write a whole programming language (but the first few chapters build just what you want: a calculator).

Comment: Side-note: `return (num == "0" or num == "1" or ... or num == "9")` can be spelled both more succinctly and more efficiently as `return num in {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}`, which, on modernish Python (3.2+ IIRC), makes a `frozenset` at compile time and reuses it for each use, changing a `O(n)` set of tests to an average case `O(1)` test (and being shorter to type to boot). Same goes for the `operator` test (though the benefit is smaller when you only have four things, not 10, it's still a benefit).

Comment: Also, bare `except:` clauses are a *terrible* idea, and they're worse when they `pass` (they catch *everything*, and ignore it, including, say, the user hitting Ctrl-C, the program running out of memory, etc.). Looks like that `try`/`except` is just a lazy way to stop if you run off the end of the `str`, so catch `except IndexError:` specifically.

Comment: I recommend you implement a parse tree to parse your mathematical expression, rather than the very tedious- and error-prone string manipulation you're currently doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it. I'm not sure how... but I fixed it. I just need to figure out how to add variables to the equation now :) . Here is the code and thanks to everybody who gave ideas:

```
print("Calculator")

# All the numbers
def numbers(num):
    return num in {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}

# All the operators
def operator(oprt):
    return oprt in {"+", "-", "*", "/"}

# Removes all the spaces
def remove_spaces(string):
    string = string.replace(" ", "")
    return string

# Does the math between two numbers
def operation(string, num1, num2):
    if string == "+":
        return num1 + num2
    if string == "-":
        return num1 - num2
    if string == "*":
        return num1 * num2
    if string == "/":
        return int(num1 / num2)

# Tests how long the number is
def test_number(numstr):
    n = 0
    num = ""

    try:
        while numbers(numstr[n]):
            num += numstr[n]
            n += 1
    except:
        pass

    return(int(num), n)

# Solves the equation
def eval_equation(eq):
    negative = False

    # Removes the spaces
    eq = remove_spaces(eq)

    while True:
        try:
            # Checks if the first number is negative
            if eq[0] == "-":
                negative = True
                eq = eq[1:]

            # Solves the multiplication first
            i = 0
            eqTemp = ""
            if "*" in eq:
                try:
                    while i < len(eq):
                        if eq[i] in {"+", "-", "/"}:
                            eqTemp = eqTemp + eq[:i + 1]
                            #print(f"eqTemp = {eqTemp}")
                            eq = eq[i + 1:]
                            #print(f"eq = {eq}")
                            pass
                        if numbers(eq[i]) == True:
                            pass
                        if eq[i] == "*":
                            break                            
                            
                        i += 1
                except IndexError:
                    i = 0

            # Solves the division first
            i = 0
            eqTempDiv = ""
            if "/" in eq:
                try:
                    while i < len(eq):
                        if eq[i] in {"+", "-", "*"}:
                            eqTempDiv = eqTempDiv + eq[:i + 1]
                            #print(f"eqTemp = {eqTemp}")
                            eq = eq[i + 1:]
                            #print(f"eq = {eq}")
                            pass
                        if numbers(eq[i]) == True:
                            pass
                        if eq[i] == "/":
                            break                            
                            
                        i += 1
                except IndexError:
                    i = 0

            # Checks the lenght of the number
            number1 = test_number(eq)[0]

            # Returns the "-" in the negative number
            if negative == True:
                number1 = -number1
                negative = False

            # Removes the first number from the string to continue with the next
            endNumber1 = test_number(eq)[1]
            eq = eq[endNumber1:]

            # Checks for any more numbers
            if eqTempDiv == "":
                if eqTemp == "":
                    if eq == "":
                        return number1

            # This is the operator sign
            op = eq[0]
            eq = eq[1:]

            # Repeats the same process with the other number
            number2 = test_number(eq)[0]
            endNumber2 = test_number(eq)[1]

            result = operation(op, number1, number2)
            
            # Takes the result and passes it as to the first number along with the rest of the equation
            number1 = result
            eq = str(number1) + eq[endNumber2:]

            eq = eqTemp + eqTempDiv + eq
            #print(f"eqTemp final = {eqTemp}")
            #print(f"eq final = {eq}")

        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
            break
    
    return number1
    

# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        equation = input(": ")
        print(eval_equation(equation))
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Sorry, gotta get back to work, wasn't able to figure out your exact problem. I would suggest starting over on the `eval_equation` function as it's quite messy, and will be prone to bugs if you continue adding to it.

Unrelated to the actual question, here's an example of how you might improve a couple of functions a bit. Note the use of `in`, the docstrings, as well as a more clear function name.

```
def is_num(num):
    """Determine if the character is a number."""
    return num in '0123456789'

def is_oprt(oprt):
    """Determine if the character is an operator."""
    return oprt in '+-*/'
```

Your `test_number` function also can be optimised a little by iterating over the string rather than using `while` with `try/except`. It's a bit more personal preference but this is how I'd do it:

```
def get_num(numstr):
    """Gets the number at the start of a string."""
    num = []
    for i, c in enumerate(numstr):
        if not is_num(c):
            break
        num.append(c)
    try:
        return int(''.join(num)), i + 1
    except ValueError:
        return 0, 0
```

One other syntax suggestion:

```
number2 = test_number(eq)[0]
endNumber2 = test_number(eq)[1]
```

Is the same as:

```
number2, endNumber2 = test_number(eq)
```

Comment: also: `num.isdigit()`.

Comment: True, did cross my mind, though I thought I'd keep the functionality the exact same to avoid confusing things :)